# How would i optimise this if statement

Tags: c#

Im finally done with my project and im going through my code and optimising it and trying to cut down on the chunky lines of code, how would i optimize this, it a series of if statments that matches text and adds value to a corresponding text box

```
private void btnfinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Daily Sales
            for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Manga vol 1-5 ")
                {
                    var Book1 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book1 = Book1 + Global.Book1;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Manga vol 6-15 ")
                {
                    var Book2 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book2 = Book2 + Global.Book2;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Novels 1-199 ")
                {
                    var Book3 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book3 = Book3 + Global.Book3;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Novels 200-400 ")
                {
                    var Book4 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book4 = Book4 + Global.Book4;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Comics series mainstream ")
                {
                    var Book5 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book5 = Book5 + Global.Book5;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Comics series secondary ")
                {
                    var Book6 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book6 = Book6 + Global.Book6;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Text book 1 semester/2 modules ")
                {
                    var Book7 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book7 = Book7 + Global.Book7;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Text book module add-ons ")
                {
                    var Book8 = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Book8 = Book8 + Global.Book8;
                }
                else if (POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "Hardcover ")
                {
                    var Hardcover = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                    Global.Hardcover = Hardcover + Global.Hardcover;
                }
            }
```

thx for the help

Comment: Well if you want to cut down on the "chunky lines of code" - then the two bits of common code could be assigned to local variables at the top of the loop. The if statements could be replaced by a switch statement. As far as optimizing is concerned - the compiler probably does that anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [CodeReview](https://codeReview.StackExchange.com)

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't know code review was a thing, ill move it now

Comment: @ZoharPeled The question as-is is off-topic on CodeReview, as it does not contain enough context to get reviewed. Also, the existence of another site doesn't change the off-topic requirements here on SO. In other words: please always point to SO's off-topic rules in its [help/dont-ask], not to other sites.

Comment: @Zeta though I didn't see a specific off-topic reason here on SO about improving working code, this type of questions is known to be less appropriate here. In fact, the CodeReview help center's have a list of questions that if you can answer "yes" to all of them, your question is on-topic. Unless the code doesn't belong to the OP, this requirement is fulfilled and therefor this question is on-topic there.

Comment: @ZoharPeled If you didn't see an off-topic reason for this kind of question in SO's help center, is the question really off-topic? See also [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287400/does-being-on-topic-at-another-stack-exchange-site-automatically-make-a-question). If you think it's too broad or needs more focus, well, those are both perfectly valid close reasons.

Comment: @Zeta No, it's not off-topic here - however I do believe it's a better fit to CodeReview. A question doesn't need to be off-topic on one site to fit better to another one - a lot of questions can be a good fit to more than once StackExchange website.

Answer (score 5):

By using a dictionary:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<int>>
{
    ["Manga vol 1-5 "] = book => Global.Book1 += book,
    ["Manga vol 6-15 "] = book => Global.Book2 += book
    //...
};
```

Then:

```
for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    var book = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    var action = actions[POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()];
    action(book);
}
```

Or using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var row in POSDGV.Rows)
{
    var book = Int32.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
    var action = actions[row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()];
    action(book);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use switch with strings

```
    private void btnfinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Daily Sales
        for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            var value = POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            var book = Int32.Parse(POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Manga vol 1-5 ":
                {
                    Global.Book1 = Book + Global.Book1;
                    break;
                }
                //other cases
            }
        }
    }
```

Using foreach makes it much more readable

```
    private void btnfinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Daily Sales
        foreach (var row in POSDGV.Rows)
        {
            var value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            var book = Int32.Parse(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Manga vol 1-5 ":
                {
                    Global.Book1 = Book + Global.Book1;
                    break;
                }
                //other cases
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private void btnfinalize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Daily Sales
    for (int i = 0; i < POSDGV.Rows.Count; ++i)
    {
        string str1 = POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string str2 = POSDGV.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        var Book = Int32.Parse(str2);

        if (str1 == "Manga vol 1-5 ")
        {
            Global.Book1 = Book + Global.Book1;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Manga vol 6-15 ")
        {
            Global.Book2 = Book + Global.Book2;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Novels 1-199 ")
        {
            Global.Book3 = Book + Global.Book3;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Novels 200-400 ")
        {
            Global.Book4 = Book + Global.Book4;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Comics series mainstream ")
        {
            Global.Book5 = Book + Global.Book5;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Comics series secondary ")
        {
            Global.Book6 = Book + Global.Book6;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Text book 1 semester/2 modules ")
        {
            Global.Book7 = Book + Global.Book7;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Text book module add-ons ")
        {
            Global.Book8 = Book + Global.Book8;
        }
        else if (str1 == "Hardcover ")
        {
            var Hardcover = Int32.Parse(str2);
            Global.Hardcover = Hardcover + Global.Hardcover;
        }
    }
}
```

Using a variable will lessen the characters in a code. You can also try using **enumerations** so you can use switch-case.

Comment: As str2 is always converted to Int32 - then that could be done at the top of the loop.

Comment: you can use `switch` on strings also, you don't have to use `enums`.

Comment: `if (str ==` should be `if (str1 ==`. And the initialisation of `str2` should be using `Cells[1]`, not `Cells[0]`.

Comment: @PaulF the str2 also uses 'i' so it couldn't be outside the loop.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes yes. my bad

Comment: @Untargeted: I said "top of the loop" NOT outside the loop - exactly as you have done - though I would have done it in a single statement as str2 is not used anywhere else. You could also use += for all of the additions of Book.

Comment: @PaulF I see. you are welcome to edit the answer as you may see fit.

Comment: @Untargeted: Sometime ago I had one of my answers downvoted quite significantly - what really annoyed me was being downvoted because somebody had edited my answer & made mistakes - my original answer was correct. So I will comment on answers to suggest improvements & leave it up to the poster to decide on whether or not to change their answer.